# How can I add the bibliography as a numbered entry in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, bibliographies

My table of contents currently looks as follows:

> 1 Introduction
>   2 Related Work
>   3 xyz
>   …
>   …
>   …
>   8 conclusions
>   References

However, I would like "References" to be numbered (9). How can I do that?